# CMake Error at: string sub-command STRIP requires two arguments

Tags: cmake, makefile, build

I'm trying to compile something, but this error is always happening.
This is the code of the file that is "causing" the error.

```
#message("${GIT_EXECUTABLE}")
if(GIT_EXECUTABLE)
    execute_process(COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} describe --tags --always OUTPUT_VARIABLE KYTY_GIT_VERSION)
else()
    set(KYTY_GIT_VERSION "unknown")
endif()
string(STRIP ${KYTY_GIT_VERSION} KYTY_GIT_VERSION)
configure_file(${INPUT_FILE} ${OUTPUT_FILE})
```

Can someone help me? I'm trying to figure it out about what to do, but I can't find the problem.

Comment: Looks like `KYTY_GIT_VERSION` variable is **empty**, so your `string` command is viewed as `string(STRIP KYTY_GIT_VERSION)`: this is what the error message is talking about. For debug `execute_process` call you could add to it RESULT_VARIABLE, ERROR_VARIABLE or other options, as described in [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html).

Comment: Like this? "if(GIT_EXECUTABLE)
    execute_process(COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} describe --tags --always  OUTPUT_VARIABLE RESULT_VARIABLE KYTY_GIT_VERSION) " This will solve the strip problem?

Comment: Have you read documentation I referred to? Keyword RESULT_VARIABLE requires additional parameter which denotes a variable name. You need to check that variable for determine whether `execute_process` has been succeeded or not.

Comment: Then can I put "0" as a variable for the result variable? I'm a beginner, so I need help with this.

Comment: "Then can I put "0" as a variable for the result variable?" - Parameter for RESULT_VARIABLE should be a **name** of the variable, not the value.  That variable will be set by `execute_process` itself to contain **actual** result of the command's execution. Checking that variable will help you to detect that the command you executed has failed. As you could guess, failed `git describe` won't produce output meaningful as a version value.

Comment: You could always put the variable in quotes to ensure the empty string is used even if `KYTY_GIT_VERSION` is empty. This may not get you the desired results though, since you probably assume the variable is non-empty. `string(STRIP "${KYTY_GIT_VERSION}" KYTY_GIT_VERSION)`